# Electric Field At Centre Of Non Uniform Ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

[image]

In the above solved example why only the **cos** components have been taken for calculation of electric field at centre ? Why not the **sine** components ? BTW in case you say that the sine components cancel out, please tell me why will they cancel out?

SOURCE:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kubLfWCIWv0 (I came across this video just sometime ago and had the above doubt.So please help!!)

Comment: From my point of view,he should have calculated both the cos and sin components and then take the square root of their sums squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **sin** components actually will cancel out because in the integral you will have $\cos\theta\sin\theta$ which is equal to $\sin(2\theta )/2$,which if you integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$ will give you zero.
I do not know how to explain it intuitively,i think that you can not predict this result by "physics intuition",but only with mathematics intuition(some might predict it based on the cos function of the charge distribution).
So, don't fret about it.

Comment: I wonder how the guy who made the video directly said the "sine" components cancel out! lol :-P! Anyway thanks a lot Landos!

Comment: Yeah,me too.If you ever learn,please share it here.By the way,maybe you should change your video lectures,because a good teacher would explain this.Khan academy lectures are great.And there are also academic lectures in youtube.Try Yale's

Answer (score 0):

There is an intuitive reason why the electric field cancels at the center. Notice that the charge distribution is a cosine function, which means that if you stay at the center and watch at any specific direction, the charge at the opposite direction will have the opposite sign, and will cancel out the net force. This happens for any arbitrary direction of your choice.

Comment: If the charge at the opposite direction has the opposite sign, It will double the  force at the center. However when you consider the resultant over charges from all directions, only the vertical component cancels out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: the solution of problem is given in the pix]![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Sat.jpg

Comment: You should typeset this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answers are missing physical intuition, so I will try to explain it intuitively.

Also, note that this works only because the linear charge density is fucntion of cosine, had it been a complex one, this approach would become more hectic that using integration.

So, we know cosine function is positive in 1st and 4th quadrants and negative otherwise. Hence the ring will have positive and negative charges in the respective quadrants. Let the test charge at the centre be positive. Notice how the left side will try to pull the charge towards left while the right side will push it, again to the left. So the x component of electric field doesn't cancel. Now you can clearly see why the y component cancels out.

I know I am late but hopefully this will help someone.